# Java Spring MongoRepository - Override and use "super" or make a public function private

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

### Override and call super

I'd like to override the save function and internally call it.

```
public interface DataRepo extends MongoRepository<Data, String> {

    @Query("{'hash' : ?0}")
    List<Data> findDataByHash(String hash);

    default Boolean isHashSaved(String hash) {
        return findDataByHash(hash).size() > 0;
    }

    @Override
    default Data save(Data entity) {
        if (isHashSaved(entity.hash)) return null;
        // return (Data) MongoRepository.save(entity);   // not working
        // return (Data) super.save(entity);             // not working
    }
}
```

### Or hide functions

```
public interface DataRepo extends MongoRepository<Data, String> {

    @Override
    "private" default Data save(Data entity) {         <------- Can I hide this?
        if (isHashSaved(entity.hash)) return null;
        return (Data) MongoRepository.save(entity);
    }

}
```